# What is the Cambodian bar Anthony Bourdain mentions where you can shoot a gun?

Tags: cambodia, nightlife, locate-this, firearms

In [this podcast](https://youtu.be/28Qzxz5wsA0?t=32m52s) Anthony Bourdain talks about a bar in Cambodia where you can drink and shoot a firearm:

> There’s a bar in Cambodia that’s really famous... They give you liquor
>   for free. You pay for ammunition by the round.

What is this bar/shooting range called and where is it exactly? I Googled and found lots of shooting ranges in Cambodia but no places explicitly advertised as being a bar *and* a shooting range.

Comment: It must be the [Cambodia Firing Range Outdoor Phnom Penh](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g293940-d8417222-Reviews-Cambodia_Firing_Range_Outdoor_Phnom_Penh-Phnom_Penh.html)? It's not actually a bar, it is a firing range where you get liquor from what I read in some of the reviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be the [Cambodia Firing Range Outdoor Phnom Penh](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g293940-d8417222-Reviews-Cambodia_Firing_Range_Outdoor_Phnom_Penh-Phnom_Penh.html). It's not actually a bar, it is a firing range where you get liquor from what I read in some of the reviews

Answer (score 1):

Not sure were. There are a number of older clubs in Asia. Roots in colonial times. Were you can go to shoot skeet. Then when done go into the club house. Have a drink or 2. Then set & relax & talk. Kind of like golf clubs in America. You play the game then go to the club house to talk about it. Here the old fishing club on the island in the bay. Also the New sports club in the upper Balulang. Both you would need a invitation to. So sounds like a upper crust club to me. They do exist.